# Sum of elements in a list at the same position

Tags: list, haskell, nested, sum, fold

How can I do the sum of elements in a list at the same position?
For example:

```
[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]=[15,18,21]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sumIn :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumIn = foldl (zipWith (+)) (repeat 0)
```

Note that if the argument is an empty list, the result is an infinite list of zeros. So you may want to treat this case separately, for example

```
sumIn :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumIn [] = []
sumIn xs = foldl (zipWith (+)) (repeat 0) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose the list, and sum each list in the result:

```
ghci> import Data.List (transpose)
ghci> map sum $ transpose [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
[15,18,21]
```

Unlike the other solutions, this works for lists of non-uniform length.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in GHCi:

```
λ> let xs = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
λ> foldr1 (zipWith (+)) xs
[15,18,21]
```

Comment: And if I want to add to other list a 0 if it is even and a 1 otherwise? Thanks

Comment: You could define `f x = if even x then 0 else 1`, and then `map f` onto the the result above. So `map f [15,18,21]` would give you `[1,0,1]`. Is that what you want?